# Same Azure Function, same input, different tenant, different output

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

Stumped as to where to go next with this issue.

My node.js azure function takes in a file represented as base64. It does some processing on the file and returns the processed file in the response:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {

    const buf = Buffer.from(req.body.file, 'base64')

    /// do processing

    const file = filebuf.toString('base64')

    context.res.status(200).json({ file })
}
```

So in my personal Azure tenant this works fine. In my clients azure tenant, the file is corrupted.  This is with the same exact file as input.

Not sure if its interesting but the first few bytes of the different tenants processed files are as so:

```
{
    "file": "UEsDBAoAAAAAAGh+r1SoFh7uRAwAAEQMAAA..."
}



{
    "file": "UEsDBAoAAAAAANh8r1SoFh7uRAwAAEQMAAA..."
}
```

For some reason, around the 14th char is different and I can't think why that would be. Both function apps are running on Linux and the runtime version of the apps are the same.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Following the first answer and my new understanding that the different byte is to be expected I am still not closer to understanding why one file is corrupt and another is not.

I now notice that the content length of the body is different:

Non-corrupt:

```
"headers":{"Transfer-Encoding":"chunked","Vary":"Accept-Encoding","Strict-Transport-Security":"max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains","x-ms-apihub-cached-response":"true","x-ms-apihub-obo":"true","Cache-Control":"private","Date":"Mon, 16 May 2022 08:25:38 GMT","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Content-Length":"2926356"}
```

Corrupt:

```
"headers":{"Transfer-Encoding":"chunked","Request-Context":"appId=cid-v1:XXX","x-ms-apihub-cached-response":"true","x-ms-apihub-obo":"true","Date":"Mon, 16 May 2022 08:24:48 GMT","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Content-Length":"2926368"}
```

Where could these extra bytes have come from? I wondering if it might be between different versions of Node but would be surprised.

Answer (score 2):

The 2 bytes which are different are part of the ZIP file header and describe the **modification time**.

Let's take a look at the first partial base64 string

```
base64
UEsDBAoAAAAAAGh+r1SoFh7uRAwAAEQMAAA

hex
50 4b 03 04 0a 00 00 00 00 00 68 7e af 54 a8 16 1e ee 44 0c 00 00 44 0c 00 00
```

The first 4 bytes `50 4b 03 04` are the ZIP file signature, `0a 00` the version, `00 00` the flags, `00 00` the compression method and finally `68 7e` the file modification time. This is in MS-DOS format which translates to 13:03:15. Needless to say the different time values in there do not indicate a corrupted file.

More information on the ZIP format: https://users.cs.jmu.edu/buchhofp/forensics/formats/pkzip.html

Comment: Thanks Christian - thats really interesting and something new I've learned! As you say different time values are to be expected. I still need to understand why one output is corrupted and the other is not

Comment: It might be worth trying to save the uploaded ZIP file in your Azure Function, then download it manually and check the file integrity (e.g. on Linux with unzip -t). It also reminds me of an issue with Azure Functions I created some time ago where the function app nodejs worker did something fishy with the request as well (see https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker/issues/294). Do you and your client use the same method to upload the file (e.g. curl, Postman)? Can you check the Content-Type header of your request to the function?

Comment: Thanks Christian - you prompted me to do some more testing via postman and node's http.request function from which I called the Azure function separately and saved the file. Doing it this way I can confirm that it is not corrupt. This rules out Azure functions being the issue. I'll close this as its no longer a valid question